# Replace rating numbers with stars in a shiny app but im taking NAs instead

Tags: r, shiny

i want to produxe a table in shiny with stars symboles instead of rating numbers but i take NAs instead.

library(shiny)

```
nba <- data.frame(
  player = c("James", "Durant", "Curry", "Harden", "Paul", "Wade"), 
  team = c("CLEOH", "GSWOAK", "GSWOAK", "HOUTX", "HOUTX", "CLEOH"),
  day1points = c("25","23","30","41","26","20"), 
  day2points = c("24","25","33","45","26","23"),
  rating=c("1","2","3","4","5","1")
)
strrep("\U2605", as.numeric(nba$rating))
ui <- navbarPage(
  title="SADDAS",
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(uiOutput("var1_select")),
    mainPanel(tableOutput("reportOutput"))
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$var1_select<-renderUI({
    selectInput("ind_var_select","Select Names", choices =c(as.character(nba[,1] )),multiple = TRUE,selected = nba[1,1])
  })
  output$reportOutput = renderTable({
    nba[,1:5][nba$player %in% input$ind_var_select,]
  },
  options = list(scrollX = TRUE)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be `strrep`

```
nba$rating <- strrep("*", nba$rating)
nba$rating
#[1] "*"     "**"    "***"   "****"  "*****" "*"
```

We could use fancy stars by looking at the Utf symbols

```
strrep("\U2605", nba$rating)
#[1] "★"     "★★"    "★★★"   "★★★★"  "★★★★★" "★"
```

or if we need a white star

```
strrep("\U2606", nba$rating)
#[1] "☆"     "☆☆"    "☆☆☆"   "☆☆☆☆"  "☆☆☆☆☆" "☆"
```

Comment: I guess that will replace with * but i want the real star thing. I guess it needs some kind of javascript.

Comment: @MakisKasvikis  You can look for the utf value for the real start and then replace the `*` with that

Comment: Somethin like this u mean U+1F31F

Comment: @MakisKasvikis  I updated with some stars.  Could you please check

Comment: I did it but i take NAs with UTF codes. I guess is the encoding

Comment: btw i have utf-8 encoding in RStudio

Comment: What are your settings and you can display it normally?

Comment: Try with utf-16

Comment: finalPredictionData1$`Score` <- strrep("\U2605",finalPredictionData1$`Score` )
    finalPredictionData1$`Score`<- stri_encode(finalPredictionData1$`Score`, "", "UTF-16")

Comment: @MakisKasvikis  Not clear aboout `not working` as the `strrep(`\U2605'` is working fine for me